# How do I pull a specific variable from the SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, console-application, datareader

I'm working on a currency conversion project, now I've built a little script to pull the conversion rates and descriptions out of my database, but I can't seem to find a way to pull the variable (Rate) out of the string the datareader has created.

Here is the code snippet:

```
            if (reader.HasRows)
                //The reader will only read the rows if the ISO code matches the options avalible within the DB
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result Found!");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rate: {0}\t Conversion Rate: {1}",
                                      reader[0], reader[1]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
```

Now I want the Rate variable which is a decimal without having to convert it or shove it in an adapter (I'm new at C#).

tl;dr
I want the output from "Rate: {0}" alone so I can use it to convert the currency's.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
reader.ReadField<type>("fieldname") ?
```

EDIT:   Wow, I can't believe I forgot that this was not part of SqlDataReader :p, I was just looking at my implementation... code for this:

Extension:

```
public static T ReadField<T>(this IDataReader reader, String fieldname)
{
    return DB.ReaderField<T>(reader, fieldname);
}
```

DB.ReaderField:

```
public static T ReaderField<T>(IDataReader reader, String fieldname)
{
    try
    {
        int idx = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldname);
        if (reader.IsDBNull(idx))
        {
            return (T)default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            object o = reader.GetValue(idx);

            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
            }
            catch
            {
                return (T)default(T);
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return (T)default(T);
}
```

Sorry about the confusion :)

Comment: Huh? That's not a standard [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods.aspx) method, is it? Did you write an extension for that?

Comment: Maybe he meant [GetFieldValue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh485652.aspx).

Comment: Oh neat, definitely improves efficiency! I'd +1 you but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

The DataReader doesn't create a string.

You can call `reader.GetDecimal(0)`.